question about Milo SDK SubscriptionListener
Have a question about Milo SDK SubscriptionListener:
When the event onSubscriptionTransferFailed is triggered, we need to recreate the subscription, but do we still need to call the OpcUaSubscriptionManager.deleteSubscription to clear the old subscription before creating a new subscription?
searched online, did not find answer.

You don't need to call deleteSubscription.

Thank you Kevin for your quick response!
I have a related question about resource cleaning, if I decide to call client.disconnect(), before that do I still need to manually delete all subscriptions, and monitored items, or Milo will do the resource cleaning automatically?
Thanks in advance!

Calling disconnect() sends a CloseSessionRequest with the deleteSubscriptions parameter set to true - there should be nothing left to clean up. If you will re-use the OpcUaClient instance it might be wise to call OpcUaSubscriptionManager::clearSubscriptions on the client side.
